# How to invoke custom method in GraphQL::Schema

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, graphql, graphql-ruby

I am trying to add a check in GraphQL::Schema. I want to call a method where I have defined my schema.
One Way is to call the method in GraphqlController. But, I am not able to get the arguments that are sent in the mutation/query only the query string.
For example, I want custom validation across all mutations and queries.

```
class MySchema < GraphQL::Schema
  #my method to be called for each query/mutation
  mutation(Types::MutationType)
  query(Types::QueryType)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `params[:variables]` ?  There is also something like schema filtering: 
https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/blob/master/guides/schema/limiting_visibility.md